# How to refresh Angular application after build library?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have an Angular 8 application that includes a `library` and an `application`.

- My-Workspace

  - projects

    - my-lib (library)
    - my-lib-test (application)

And I have run a command in terminal `ng build --watch=true`. This watches any changes in library and build it immediately.

I added library to `my-lib-test` project. And I run command `ng-serve my-lib-test`. But when I changed the library, my application does not refresh in browser.

Why?

Comment: See [this](https://medium.com/@ntkolev/angular-6-build-watch-multiple-dependent-libraries-in-one-shell-562a5131788c) article

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to use:

> npm install

For updating every libraries and packages.